# How do create a Hex encoded HmacSHA256 secure hash in JS?

Tags: javascript, encryption, hmac

I have a project with the following Java Code that works...

```
static String generateHashKey (String apiKey, String msg) throws GeneralSecurityException{

    Mac hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    hmacSha256.init(secretKey);
    byte[] bytes = hmacSha256.doFinal(msg.getBytes());

    return Hex.encodeHexString(bytes).replace("-","");
}
```

I am trying to replace this with a js function like...

```
import crypto from "crypto";
...
const eMessage = crypto.createHmac("SHA256", apiKey).update(message).digest("base64");
```

But it looks to be producing different hashes. How do I ensure the same hash for both? What am I missing?

*UPDATE*

Per the comment and link I tried

```
import crypto from "crypto";
import fs from "fs";
import moment from "moment";
import axios from "axios";
import hmacSHA256 from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha256';
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';
import Base64 from 'crypto-js/enc-base64';
....
const eMessage = Base64.stringify(hmacSHA256(message, key));
const eMessage2 = crypto.createHmac("SHA256", key).update(message).digest("base64");
console.log(eMessage)
console.log(eMessage2)
```

Both of the JS libs return the same (Which is good) but it doesn't match the Java which is bad.

Comment: Potentially: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#js

Comment: Thanks added update

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use this on node.js:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
const signature = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', key)
    .update(message)
    .digest('hex')
console.log('Signature:', signature)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I was having was that it was not in base64 and was instead in Hex...

```
import hmacSHA256 from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha256';
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';
import Hex from 'crypto-js/enc-hex'
const bytes = hmacSHA256(message, key);
const eMessage = bytes.toString(Hex);
```